# How to prove a function is well defined

Tags: functions, cardinals

Let B be the set of all infinite cardinals b such that $b^2 = b$.

I need to show that this function:

$$λb ∈ B.ιx (x^b = 2^b)  and (∀c.(c>x) → (c^b > 2^b))$$

is well defined. It seems like everything I try doesnt hold $c^b > 2^b$

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question using http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You're using the (awful, imo) notation for function from lambda calculus. Experience shows that chances are not many *mathematicians* around this place either  know or else really like this notation. If you can put your question without that notation I think there's a better chance more people will understand/like it and you could get, probably, more help.

Comment: See my answer to [your later question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079680/finding-a-singluar-cardinality).\