# Finding a singluar cardinality

Tags: cardinals

Given an infinite cardinal b such that $b^2=b$ I need to find a cardinal $x$ such that:

$$(x^b = 2^b)\quad  \land \quad (\forall c.(c>x)\to   (c^b>2^b))$$

Furthermore, I need to show there is only one such $x$.

I think the answer is  $ x = 2^b$ but have trouble proving the second part:$$(c>2^b) \to (c^b >2^b) $$

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly is $b$?

Comment: $c>2^b \rightarrow c^b \geq c> 2^b $

Comment: I don't know what $b$ is, but presumably if there's only one $x$ such that $x^b=2^b$ and (statement) then that $x$ is $2$.

Comment: b and c are infinite cardinals

Comment: I edited the question, forgot a part of the question

Comment: The question is missing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $x=2^b$ satisfies the given conditions: $x^b=\left(2^b\right)^b=2^{b^2}=2^b=x$, and if $c>x=2^b$, then $c^b\ge c>2^b$. To show uniqueness, suppose that $y$ is an infinite cardinal such that $y^b=2^b$, and $c^b>2^b$ whenever $c>y$. Then on the one hand we must have $y\le x$, since $y^b=2^b$, but on the other hand we must have $x\le y$, since $x^b=2^b$, so $x=y$.